# SVG - Out of viewBox

Tags: svg

In the following SVG, some objects appearing out of viewBox (part of them such as 1). The question is how can we specify automatically that they are out of viewBox and how can we solve this problem?

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="M1-1" height="53.3899pt" version="1.1" width="365.631pt" viewBox="0 0 365.631 53.3899" style="background:yellow">
  <g id="B1-1">
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,0,19.477)">
      <path id="g113-9" d="M162 -163V703H101V-163H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,3.432,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,7.947,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-71" d="M584 650H137L131 622C214 614 217 612 200 521L125 127C109 41 101 35 23 28L17 0H288L294 28C201 35 193 42 209 128L242 309H348C440 309 442 300 443 226H471L510 422H482C452 354 449 348 357 348H251L295 575C302 609 304 615 338 615H426C502 615 517 604 526 581C534 560 536 524 537 492L565 494C574 554 583 631 584 650Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,15.842,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-118" d="M515 96L502 119C471 88 431 62 423 62C416 62 411 70 417 101C440 223 469 341 497 448H486L412 422L380 277C330 188 210 57 152 57C137 57 126 69 139 124L195 366C210 431 205 448 182 448C155 448 89 413 23 350L36 326C73 354 103 376 112 376C118 376 118 365 113 340L61 118C54 90 52 68 52 51C52 0 75 -12 98 -12S151 -3 181 17C242 58 305 119 362 193H364L345 104C323 3 339 -12 359 -12C390 -12 464 35 515 96Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,22.836,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,29.582,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,34.096,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-117" d="M324 430H196L233 583L223 592L145 529L120 430H54L29 396L31 388H111L56 126C33 15 54 -12 77 -12C137 -12 214 57 250 95L233 119C208 92 155 59 138 59C126 59 120 70 131 125L186 390L298 394L324 430Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,38.53,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,45.966,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-33" d="M535 230V280H52V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,56.531,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,61.046,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-71" d="M584 650H137L131 622C214 614 217 612 200 521L125 127C109 41 101 35 23 28L17 0H288L294 28C201 35 193 42 209 128L242 309H348C440 309 442 300 443 226H471L510 422H482C452 354 449 348 357 348H251L295 575C302 609 304 615 338 615H426C502 615 517 604 526 581C534 560 536 524 537 492L565 494C574 554 583 631 584 650Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,68.941,19.236)">
      <path id="g185-40" d="M219 86C216 168 211 250 206 337C201 410 189 448 163 448C131 448 79 396 43 344L60 322C91 359 110 375 118 375S132 358 136 298C141 238 152 81 155 -12H182C242 62 331 177 390 258C435 321 451 360 451 391C450 424 432 448 408 448C390 448 372 435 366 419C362 410 362 401 366 394C373 383 376 367 376 350C376 283 262 138 221 86H219Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,74.805,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,81.546,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,86.061,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-117" d="M324 430H196L233 583L223 592L145 529L120 430H54L29 396L31 388H111L56 126C33 15 54 -12 77 -12C137 -12 214 57 250 95L233 119C208 92 155 59 138 59C126 59 120 70 131 125L186 390L298 394L324 430Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,90.494,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,95.025,19.477)">
      <path id="g113-9" d="M162 -163V703H101V-163H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,102.089,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-93" d="M531 71V127L115 310L531 494V550L57 335V285L531 71ZM531 -40V10H57V-40H531Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,3.564)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,7.166)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,10.767)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,14.369)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,17.97)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,21.572)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,25.173)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,28.774)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,32.376)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,116.784,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-50" d="M384 0V27C293 34 287 42 287 114V635C232 613 172 594 109 583V559L157 557C201 555 205 550 205 499V114C205 42 199 34 109 27V0H384Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,125.929,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-33" d="M535 230V280H52V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,147.589,10.728)">
      <path id="g113-117" d="M324 430H196L233 583L223 592L145 529L120 430H54L29 396L31 388H111L56 126C33 15 54 -12 77 -12C137 -12 214 57 250 95L233 119C208 92 155 59 138 59C126 59 120 70 131 125L186 390L298 394L324 430Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.0091,0,0,-0.0091,152.022,4.987)">
      <path id="g50-50" d="M389 0V32C297 38 291 46 291 118V635C234 613 175 595 109 583V556L161 554C203 552 207 547 207 497V118C207 46 201 38 110 32V0H389Z" />
    </g>
    <rect x="152.022" height="0.484101" width="4.94643" y="6.439" />
    <rect x="137.69" height="0.65243" width="29.1943" y="15.582" />
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,137.69,28.461)">
      <path id="g113-85" d="M620 675H597C578 656 570 650 541 650H144C112 650 104 653 94 675H72C59 618 42 552 23 493L53 491C71 534 88 564 105 585C124 608 144 615 238 615H290L197 121C182 40 174 34 88 28L82 0H361L367 28C275 34 266 38 281 121L374 615H441C522 615 543 608 553 583C562 560 566 531 565 493L597 494C603 551 612 629 620 675Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,148.88,28.461)">
      <path id="g117-36" d="M535 230V280H323V490H265V280H52V230H265V-3H323V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,159.417,28.461)">
      <path id="g113-223" d="M545 106L524 126C493 85 467 65 455 65C438 65 427 113 405 238C448 295 498 362 543 439L533 448L478 435C453 386 423 331 398 295H395C370 404 347 448 282 448C169 448 23 309 23 153C23 54 65 -12 128 -12C203 -12 283 70 339 155H341C360 29 380 -12 411 -12C444 -12 491 11 545 106ZM333 204C265 95 210 54 169 54C137 54 113 96 113 171C113 302 191 405 252 405C301 405 318 306 333 204Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,3.564)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,7.166)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,10.767)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,14.369)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,17.97)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,21.572)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,25.173)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,28.774)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,32.376)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,173.714,12.568)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,173.714,16.17)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,173.714,19.771)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,173.714,23.372)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,177.146,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-122" d="M556 393C556 426 537 448 514 448C496 448 478 435 471 420C468 414 462 401 466 394C473 382 480 368 480 346C480 268 392 143 338 67H336C329 163 319 253 309 330S286 448 254 448C215 448 160 383 127 337L143 311C167 344 200 373 208 373S222 365 229 320C246 214 264 66 268 -20C219 -83 131 -171 17 -239L25 -261L137 -235C248 -110 273 -79 335 8C384 77 481 215 520 287C544 332 556 363 556 393Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,186.854,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,191.369,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-118" d="M515 96L502 119C471 88 431 62 423 62C416 62 411 70 417 101C440 223 469 341 497 448H486L412 422L380 277C330 188 210 57 152 57C137 57 126 69 139 124L195 366C210 431 205 448 182 448C155 448 89 413 23 350L36 326C73 354 103 376 112 376C118 376 118 365 113 340L61 118C54 90 52 68 52 51C52 0 75 -12 98 -12S151 -3 181 17C242 58 305 119 362 193H364L345 104C323 3 339 -12 359 -12C390 -12 464 35 515 96Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,198.363,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,205.809,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-33" d="M535 230V280H52V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,216.375,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-122" d="M556 393C556 426 537 448 514 448C496 448 478 435 471 420C468 414 462 401 466 394C473 382 480 368 480 346C480 268 392 143 338 67H336C329 163 319 253 309 330S286 448 254 448C215 448 160 383 127 337L143 311C167 344 200 373 208 373S222 365 229 320C246 214 264 66 268 -20C219 -83 131 -171 17 -239L25 -261L137 -235C248 -110 273 -79 335 8C384 77 481 215 520 287C544 332 556 363 556 393Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,226.083,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,230.598,19.236)">
      <path id="g185-40" d="M219 86C216 168 211 250 206 337C201 410 189 448 163 448C131 448 79 396 43 344L60 322C91 359 110 375 118 375S132 358 136 298C141 238 152 81 155 -12H182C242 62 331 177 390 258C435 321 451 360 451 391C450 424 432 448 408 448C390 448 372 435 366 419C362 410 362 401 366 394C373 383 376 367 376 350C376 283 262 138 221 86H219Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,236.461,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,240.998,12.568)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,240.998,16.17)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,240.998,19.771)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,240.998,23.372)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,247.387,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-36" d="M535 230V280H323V490H265V280H52V230H265V-3H323V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,269.047,10.728)">
      <path id="g113-117" d="M324 430H196L233 583L223 592L145 529L120 430H54L29 396L31 388H111L56 126C33 15 54 -12 77 -12C137 -12 214 57 250 95L233 119C208 92 155 59 138 59C126 59 120 70 131 125L186 390L298 394L324 430Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.0091,0,0,-0.0091,273.48,4.987)">
      <path id="g50-50" d="M389 0V32C297 38 291 46 291 118V635C234 613 175 595 109 583V556L161 554C203 552 207 547 207 497V118C207 46 201 38 110 32V0H389Z" />
    </g>
    <rect x="273.48" height="0.484101" width="4.94643" y="6.439" />
    <rect x="259.148" height="0.65243" width="29.1943" y="15.582" />
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,259.148,28.461)">
      <path id="g113-85" d="M620 675H597C578 656 570 650 541 650H144C112 650 104 653 94 675H72C59 618 42 552 23 493L53 491C71 534 88 564 105 585C124 608 144 615 238 615H290L197 121C182 40 174 34 88 28L82 0H361L367 28C275 34 266 38 281 121L374 615H441C522 615 543 608 553 583C562 560 566 531 565 493L597 494C603 551 612 629 620 675Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,270.338,28.461)">
      <path id="g117-36" d="M535 230V280H323V490H265V280H52V230H265V-3H323V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,280.875,28.461)">
      <path id="g113-223" d="M545 106L524 126C493 85 467 65 455 65C438 65 427 113 405 238C448 295 498 362 543 439L533 448L478 435C453 386 423 331 398 295H395C370 404 347 448 282 448C169 448 23 309 23 153C23 54 65 -12 128 -12C203 -12 283 70 339 155H341C360 29 380 -12 411 -12C444 -12 491 11 545 106ZM333 204C265 95 210 54 169 54C137 54 113 96 113 171C113 302 191 405 252 405C301 405 318 306 333 204Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,291.716,19.477)">
      <path id="g113-9" d="M162 -163V703H101V-163H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,295.148,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-66" d="M686 28C612 35 607 44 591 112C563 234 541 360 519 489L489 666L457 658L147 121C100 40 89 36 24 28L17 0H240L250 28C168 34 159 41 190 101L262 237H482C495 180 503 137 510 91C517 47 514 35 441 28L433 0H677L686 28ZM475 280H285L429 541H431L475 280Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,306.462,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,310.977,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-118" d="M515 96L502 119C471 88 431 62 423 62C416 62 411 70 417 101C440 223 469 341 497 448H486L412 422L380 277C330 188 210 57 152 57C137 57 126 69 139 124L195 366C210 431 205 448 182 448C155 448 89 413 23 350L36 326C73 354 103 376 112 376C118 376 118 365 113 340L61 118C54 90 52 68 52 51C52 0 75 -12 98 -12S151 -3 181 17C242 58 305 119 362 193H364L345 104C323 3 339 -12 359 -12C390 -12 464 35 515 96Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,317.971,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,325.418,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-33" d="M535 230V280H52V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,335.983,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-66" d="M686 28C612 35 607 44 591 112C563 234 541 360 519 489L489 666L457 658L147 121C100 40 89 36 24 28L17 0H240L250 28C168 34 159 41 190 101L262 237H482C495 180 503 137 510 91C517 47 514 35 441 28L433 0H677L686 28ZM475 280H285L429 541H431L475 280Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,347.297,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,351.812,19.236)">
      <path id="g185-40" d="M219 86C216 168 211 250 206 337C201 410 189 448 163 448C131 448 79 396 43 344L60 322C91 359 110 375 118 375S132 358 136 298C141 238 152 81 155 -12H182C242 62 331 177 390 258C435 321 451 360 451 391C450 424 432 448 408 448C390 448 372 435 366 419C362 410 362 401 366 394C373 383 376 367 376 350C376 283 262 138 221 86H219Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,357.675,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,362.212,19.477)">
      <path id="g113-9" d="M162 -163V703H101V-163H162Z" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can increase the width attribute of  the svg .. for it to properly get rendered.

Comment: @Cyril don't do that it will only increase the size of the image, not what is rendered. That is the viewBox.

Answer (score 0):

The paths you draw are outside the **viewBox**.
Changed the value to better fit your paths.

Changed the viewBox to be viewBox="-5 -5 400 50"
Where the syntax of **`viewBox=|min-x|min-y|x-size|y-size|`**

[MDN viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

[How viewBox works](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/#svg-viewbox)

Here is a working example:

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="M1-1" version="1.1" viewBox="-5 -5 400 50">
  <rect fill="yellow" x="-5" y="-5" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <g id="B1-1">
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,0,19.477)">
      <path id="g113-9" d="M162 -163V703H101V-163H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,3.432,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,7.947,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-71" d="M584 650H137L131 622C214 614 217 612 200 521L125 127C109 41 101 35 23 28L17 0H288L294 28C201 35 193 42 209 128L242 309H348C440 309 442 300 443 226H471L510 422H482C452 354 449 348 357 348H251L295 575C302 609 304 615 338 615H426C502 615 517 604 526 581C534 560 536 524 537 492L565 494C574 554 583 631 584 650Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,15.842,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-118" d="M515 96L502 119C471 88 431 62 423 62C416 62 411 70 417 101C440 223 469 341 497 448H486L412 422L380 277C330 188 210 57 152 57C137 57 126 69 139 124L195 366C210 431 205 448 182 448C155 448 89 413 23 350L36 326C73 354 103 376 112 376C118 376 118 365 113 340L61 118C54 90 52 68 52 51C52 0 75 -12 98 -12S151 -3 181 17C242 58 305 119 362 193H364L345 104C323 3 339 -12 359 -12C390 -12 464 35 515 96Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,22.836,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,29.582,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,34.096,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-117" d="M324 430H196L233 583L223 592L145 529L120 430H54L29 396L31 388H111L56 126C33 15 54 -12 77 -12C137 -12 214 57 250 95L233 119C208 92 155 59 138 59C126 59 120 70 131 125L186 390L298 394L324 430Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,38.53,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,45.966,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-33" d="M535 230V280H52V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,56.531,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,61.046,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-71" d="M584 650H137L131 622C214 614 217 612 200 521L125 127C109 41 101 35 23 28L17 0H288L294 28C201 35 193 42 209 128L242 309H348C440 309 442 300 443 226H471L510 422H482C452 354 449 348 357 348H251L295 575C302 609 304 615 338 615H426C502 615 517 604 526 581C534 560 536 524 537 492L565 494C574 554 583 631 584 650Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,68.941,19.236)">
      <path id="g185-40" d="M219 86C216 168 211 250 206 337C201 410 189 448 163 448C131 448 79 396 43 344L60 322C91 359 110 375 118 375S132 358 136 298C141 238 152 81 155 -12H182C242 62 331 177 390 258C435 321 451 360 451 391C450 424 432 448 408 448C390 448 372 435 366 419C362 410 362 401 366 394C373 383 376 367 376 350C376 283 262 138 221 86H219Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,74.805,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,81.546,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,86.061,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-117" d="M324 430H196L233 583L223 592L145 529L120 430H54L29 396L31 388H111L56 126C33 15 54 -12 77 -12C137 -12 214 57 250 95L233 119C208 92 155 59 138 59C126 59 120 70 131 125L186 390L298 394L324 430Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,90.494,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,95.025,19.477)">
      <path id="g113-9" d="M162 -163V703H101V-163H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,102.089,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-93" d="M531 71V127L115 310L531 494V550L57 335V285L531 71ZM531 -40V10H57V-40H531Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,3.564)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,7.166)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,10.767)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,14.369)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,17.97)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,21.572)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,25.173)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,28.774)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,113.352,32.376)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,116.784,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-50" d="M384 0V27C293 34 287 42 287 114V635C232 613 172 594 109 583V559L157 557C201 555 205 550 205 499V114C205 42 199 34 109 27V0H384Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,125.929,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-33" d="M535 230V280H52V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,147.589,10.728)">
      <path id="g113-117" d="M324 430H196L233 583L223 592L145 529L120 430H54L29 396L31 388H111L56 126C33 15 54 -12 77 -12C137 -12 214 57 250 95L233 119C208 92 155 59 138 59C126 59 120 70 131 125L186 390L298 394L324 430Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.0091,0,0,-0.0091,152.022,4.987)">
      <path id="g50-50" d="M389 0V32C297 38 291 46 291 118V635C234 613 175 595 109 583V556L161 554C203 552 207 547 207 497V118C207 46 201 38 110 32V0H389Z" />
    </g>
    <rect x="152.022" height="0.484101" width="4.94643" y="6.439" />
    <rect x="137.69" height="0.65243" width="29.1943" y="15.582" />
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,137.69,28.461)">
      <path id="g113-85" d="M620 675H597C578 656 570 650 541 650H144C112 650 104 653 94 675H72C59 618 42 552 23 493L53 491C71 534 88 564 105 585C124 608 144 615 238 615H290L197 121C182 40 174 34 88 28L82 0H361L367 28C275 34 266 38 281 121L374 615H441C522 615 543 608 553 583C562 560 566 531 565 493L597 494C603 551 612 629 620 675Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,148.88,28.461)">
      <path id="g117-36" d="M535 230V280H323V490H265V280H52V230H265V-3H323V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,159.417,28.461)">
      <path id="g113-223" d="M545 106L524 126C493 85 467 65 455 65C438 65 427 113 405 238C448 295 498 362 543 439L533 448L478 435C453 386 423 331 398 295H395C370 404 347 448 282 448C169 448 23 309 23 153C23 54 65 -12 128 -12C203 -12 283 70 339 155H341C360 29 380 -12 411 -12C444 -12 491 11 545 106ZM333 204C265 95 210 54 169 54C137 54 113 96 113 171C113 302 191 405 252 405C301 405 318 306 333 204Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,3.564)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,7.166)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,10.767)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,14.369)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,17.97)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,21.572)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,25.173)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,28.774)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,168.08,32.376)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,173.714,12.568)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,173.714,16.17)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,173.714,19.771)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,173.714,23.372)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,177.146,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-122" d="M556 393C556 426 537 448 514 448C496 448 478 435 471 420C468 414 462 401 466 394C473 382 480 368 480 346C480 268 392 143 338 67H336C329 163 319 253 309 330S286 448 254 448C215 448 160 383 127 337L143 311C167 344 200 373 208 373S222 365 229 320C246 214 264 66 268 -20C219 -83 131 -171 17 -239L25 -261L137 -235C248 -110 273 -79 335 8C384 77 481 215 520 287C544 332 556 363 556 393Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,186.854,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,191.369,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-118" d="M515 96L502 119C471 88 431 62 423 62C416 62 411 70 417 101C440 223 469 341 497 448H486L412 422L380 277C330 188 210 57 152 57C137 57 126 69 139 124L195 366C210 431 205 448 182 448C155 448 89 413 23 350L36 326C73 354 103 376 112 376C118 376 118 365 113 340L61 118C54 90 52 68 52 51C52 0 75 -12 98 -12S151 -3 181 17C242 58 305 119 362 193H364L345 104C323 3 339 -12 359 -12C390 -12 464 35 515 96Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,198.363,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,205.809,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-33" d="M535 230V280H52V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,216.375,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-122" d="M556 393C556 426 537 448 514 448C496 448 478 435 471 420C468 414 462 401 466 394C473 382 480 368 480 346C480 268 392 143 338 67H336C329 163 319 253 309 330S286 448 254 448C215 448 160 383 127 337L143 311C167 344 200 373 208 373S222 365 229 320C246 214 264 66 268 -20C219 -83 131 -171 17 -239L25 -261L137 -235C248 -110 273 -79 335 8C384 77 481 215 520 287C544 332 556 363 556 393Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,226.083,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,230.598,19.236)">
      <path id="g185-40" d="M219 86C216 168 211 250 206 337C201 410 189 448 163 448C131 448 79 396 43 344L60 322C91 359 110 375 118 375S132 358 136 298C141 238 152 81 155 -12H182C242 62 331 177 390 258C435 321 451 360 451 391C450 424 432 448 408 448C390 448 372 435 366 419C362 410 362 401 366 394C373 383 376 367 376 350C376 283 262 138 221 86H219Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,236.461,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,240.998,12.568)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,240.998,16.17)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,240.998,19.771)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,240.998,23.372)">
      <path id="g119-34" d="M162 0V316H101V0H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,247.387,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-36" d="M535 230V280H323V490H265V280H52V230H265V-3H323V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,269.047,10.728)">
      <path id="g113-117" d="M324 430H196L233 583L223 592L145 529L120 430H54L29 396L31 388H111L56 126C33 15 54 -12 77 -12C137 -12 214 57 250 95L233 119C208 92 155 59 138 59C126 59 120 70 131 125L186 390L298 394L324 430Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.0091,0,0,-0.0091,273.48,4.987)">
      <path id="g50-50" d="M389 0V32C297 38 291 46 291 118V635C234 613 175 595 109 583V556L161 554C203 552 207 547 207 497V118C207 46 201 38 110 32V0H389Z" />
    </g>
    <rect x="273.48" height="0.484101" width="4.94643" y="6.439" />
    <rect x="259.148" height="0.65243" width="29.1943" y="15.582" />
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,259.148,28.461)">
      <path id="g113-85" d="M620 675H597C578 656 570 650 541 650H144C112 650 104 653 94 675H72C59 618 42 552 23 493L53 491C71 534 88 564 105 585C124 608 144 615 238 615H290L197 121C182 40 174 34 88 28L82 0H361L367 28C275 34 266 38 281 121L374 615H441C522 615 543 608 553 583C562 560 566 531 565 493L597 494C603 551 612 629 620 675Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,270.338,28.461)">
      <path id="g117-36" d="M535 230V280H323V490H265V280H52V230H265V-3H323V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,280.875,28.461)">
      <path id="g113-223" d="M545 106L524 126C493 85 467 65 455 65C438 65 427 113 405 238C448 295 498 362 543 439L533 448L478 435C453 386 423 331 398 295H395C370 404 347 448 282 448C169 448 23 309 23 153C23 54 65 -12 128 -12C203 -12 283 70 339 155H341C360 29 380 -12 411 -12C444 -12 491 11 545 106ZM333 204C265 95 210 54 169 54C137 54 113 96 113 171C113 302 191 405 252 405C301 405 318 306 333 204Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,291.716,19.477)">
      <path id="g113-9" d="M162 -163V703H101V-163H162Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,295.148,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-66" d="M686 28C612 35 607 44 591 112C563 234 541 360 519 489L489 666L457 658L147 121C100 40 89 36 24 28L17 0H240L250 28C168 34 159 41 190 101L262 237H482C495 180 503 137 510 91C517 47 514 35 441 28L433 0H677L686 28ZM475 280H285L429 541H431L475 280Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,306.462,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,310.977,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-118" d="M515 96L502 119C471 88 431 62 423 62C416 62 411 70 417 101C440 223 469 341 497 448H486L412 422L380 277C330 188 210 57 152 57C137 57 126 69 139 124L195 366C210 431 205 448 182 448C155 448 89 413 23 350L36 326C73 354 103 376 112 376C118 376 118 365 113 340L61 118C54 90 52 68 52 51C52 0 75 -12 98 -12S151 -3 181 17C242 58 305 119 362 193H364L345 104C323 3 339 -12 359 -12C390 -12 464 35 515 96Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,317.971,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,325.418,19.236)">
      <path id="g117-33" d="M535 230V280H52V230H535Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,335.983,19.236)">
      <path id="g113-66" d="M686 28C612 35 607 44 591 112C563 234 541 360 519 489L489 666L457 658L147 121C100 40 89 36 24 28L17 0H240L250 28C168 34 159 41 190 101L262 237H482C495 180 503 137 510 91C517 47 514 35 441 28L433 0H677L686 28ZM475 280H285L429 541H431L475 280Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,347.297,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-41" d="M300 -147C201 -63 143 98 143 270S200 602 300 686L282 710C136 610 70 450 70 271V270C70 89 136 -72 282 -170L300 -147Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,351.812,19.236)">
      <path id="g185-40" d="M219 86C216 168 211 250 206 337C201 410 189 448 163 448C131 448 79 396 43 344L60 322C91 359 110 375 118 375S132 358 136 298C141 238 152 81 155 -12H182C242 62 331 177 390 258C435 321 451 360 451 391C450 424 432 448 408 448C390 448 372 435 366 419C362 410 362 401 366 394C373 383 376 367 376 350C376 283 262 138 221 86H219Z"
      />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,357.675,19.419)">
      <path id="g113-42" d="M275 270C275 450 212 609 64 710L45 686C145 604 203 442 203 270S147 -63 45 -147L64 -170C213 -68 275 89 275 270Z" />
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(.013,0,0,-0.013,362.212,19.477)">
      <path id="g113-9" d="M162 -163V703H101V-163H162Z" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```